# No free lunch theorem

Tags: machine-learning

Assume that learning algorithm $A$ is fixed. Let $D = \{ (x_1,y_1),\dots, (x_N,y_N) \}$, $F$ is set of a data-generating functions and $h : X \to Y$ is a classifier. $L(f(x),y) $ is $1$/$0$-loss function. Then I want to show that $$\frac{1}{|F|}\sum_{f \in F} E [L(f(q),h(q))] = \frac{1}{2}$$ where $q$ is a test point such that $x_i \neq q$ for all $i$.

---

**My attempt**

$$E[L(f(q),h(q))] = E[I_{f(q) \neq h(q) }(q)] = P(\{f(q) \neq h(q))$$ where $I_{f(q) \neq h(q) }(q)$ is an indicator function. How should i evaluate $P(\{f(q) \neq h(q)\})$?

My intuition says that $P(\{f(q)\neq h(q)\}) = \frac{1}{2}$, but I cant come up with a formal argument for that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will obviously need some assumptions on F and the sampling distribution P. What if F={f} is a singleton, for example? What if P puts all of its mass on 1 point?

Comment: Yeah then it could happen that the expected loss is 0. Any assumptions for F and P isnt given which is strange.

Comment: Well, it's *your* problem, so you get to make up the rules. Or is it homework?

Comment: Its a homework, therefore i find this quite strange that assumptions arent given.

Comment: Why don't you post the whole problem, including source -- we'll see what we can do...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lWHkiuN the problem

Comment: Where's this from? Book, page?

Comment: not a book, an exercise sheet problem 4 https://api11.ilovepdf.com/v1/download/zstzsr3vAvly9fgcsw1bsdq6ynbnb71mpsyyl71hgtl7vttfzqrnzAt80m7qpAt7fs71t7c7tAn8xp8r3z9rpx8hxr8z2swns4rrth4xvxwc7cy0ts9sysyvwth9jbnsmA7c6b10w7d2ws9yc555xm5wh2gvj89z9hf2qm7gftj3vb1j2pd1

Comment: OK, it's clear from the text that it's trying to steer you in the direction of Wolpert's papers. I found both of them here:
https://gofile.io/d/W5FbNO
You should be able to supply the relevant assumptions and quote the relevant results (acknowledging the source, of course).
As I said, without additional assumptions it's not correct.

Comment: ok thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ok i think i need to assume that data-generating functions $f$ are uniformly distributed, but im still thinking how i can define probability of "goodness" of h given f.

Comment: Presumably, that would be the “agreement” (or sample error) of $h$ w.r.t. $f$.

Comment: I dont see why i need the fact about the distribution of the data-generating functions since we are summing over all of them. And in all cases $f_i \in F$ generates $D_{f_{i}}$ anyways. Is the set $F$ a distribution instead of an original set? I think im missunderstanding something

Comment: and with the test point $q$ the classifier $h$ can make any amount of mistakes 1 or 0.

Comment: I posted an answer. Your original question didn't make it clear that $F$ is the set of *all* possible functions, which is crucial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be a finite set and $F=\{0,1\}^\Omega$ be the (finite) collection of all Boolean functions on $\Omega$. We claim that for any $h\in F$ and any distribution $P$ on $\Omega$, the following holds:
$$
(*)=\frac{1}{|F|}\sum_{f\in F}\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P}1[h(x)\neq f(x)]=\frac12.
$$
Indeed, we can treat $\frac{1}{|F|}\sum_{f\in F}$ as taking an expectation over $f\sim Q$, where $Q$ is the uniform distribution over $F$. By symmetry and Fubini's theorem (i.e., exchanging the order of the 2 expectations), this is equivalent to labeling each point $x$ independently with a Bernoulli$(1/2)$ label $B(x)$. Thus,
$$
(*)=\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P}1[h(x)\neq B(x)]=\frac12.
$$

Comment: ah so $f$ is a r.v and the test point.

Comment: Yes, the label of any $x\in\Omega$ is a r.v. *not depending* on $x$.

Comment: btw if we keep data-generating function fixed and take the average over all learning algorithms $A$ would this same argument work?

Comment: You have to formalize things correctly. For one thing, you have to assume there's a finite set of learning algorithms.

Comment: if $A$ is set of all possible algorithms then $\{ a(D) \in A\}$ is equivalent to set of classifiers where a is an algorithm and  D a fixed dataset(since algorithm $a$ outputs a classifier $h$ with dataset $D$). Or is there a case where two different algorithms output same classifier?

Comment: Formally, an algorithm is distinct from a classifier: the former maps a labeled sample to a classifier, while the latter maps a point X to a point Y. However, in the finite case, one can cheat a little and conflate the two (e.g., by stipulating that an algorithm only looks at the *set* of labeled examples -- rather than the multiset [with repeats] or the sequence [where the order matters]). Under those fixes, I think my argument works for the set of all algs as well.

Comment: do you think the solutions which i wrote is correct https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/571804/no-free-lunch-theorem-proof ? not 100% of the last step since $h$ depends from $f$.

Comment: Looks like you’re getting some pretty good feedback there.